# Can the PHP crypt function generate two same hashes when encrypting variables

Tags: php, encryption

Could code like this generate two same hashes?
(Assuming the clock is going correctly)

```
 <?php
 $t = time();
 $u = $_POST['username'];
 $st = $t.$u
 $salt = 'c5ac71cd162840eb7a4c2035ee132507';
 $e = crypt($st, $salt);
 ?>
```

Comment: You mean if the time changes? Theoretically, but it won't in practice.

Comment: @WaleedKhan That was my question: could it generate two same hashes over time? Days/months/years?

Comment: The case here would be 2 users registering at the same second with the same username. You can  change $t to: `$t = time().mt_rand();` to make that a lot less likely. And yes, it will generate the same hash over time, but that will take millions of years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of a hash and the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_hole_principle), yes, any hash produces *collisions*. One of the defining qualities of a good hash is that the chance of two inputs producing the same output are so low as to be negligible in practice.

Having said that, identical input will always produce identical output (another defining quality of a hash), and if you're going to use a static salt as input and relatively rarely changing "random" values like `time()` (it only changes every second, which is an eternity in computing), the chances of producing a collision are higher.

I cannot comment on what the correct usage of the hash here is, since I don't know what you want to use it for.